# What is an elegant way to position 8 circles around a point

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
var circles:Array = new Array();


for(var i:int = 0; i < 8; i++)
{

    var ball:Ball = new Ball();
        ball.x = ???
        ball.y = ???
        circles.push(ball);
}
```

What is the best way to position balls around some point lets say in 5-10 distance of each other, is there some formula?

Comment: there are many patterns in which you could position the balls around a point, what is your preference, or do you even want a pattern? If you just want them to make a circle around the point, use sine and cosine to position them.

Comment: I mean if we have some centerX and centerY, so how to place all the balls around those points in one loop

Comment: please can you give me a little example, i really don't have an idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    var ball:Ball = new Ball();

    // Point has a useful static function for this, it takes two parameters
    // First, length, in other words how far from the center we want to be
    // Second, it wants the angle in radians, a complete circle is 2 * Math.PI
    // So, we're multiplying that with (i / 8) to place them equally far apart
    var pos:Point = Point.polar(50, (i / 8) * Math.PI * 2);

    // Finally, set the position of the ball
    ball.x = pos.x;
    ball.y = pos.y;

    circles.push(ball);
}
```

Comment: I added some comments to the code, you can also look at the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html#polar()

Comment: x = centerX + raduis * cos( alpha / i ), y = centerY + radius * sin( alpha / i );

Answer (score 1):

I don't know actionscript3, so this exact code will not work, but it should give you a basic idea

```
for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
{
   Ball ball;
   ball.x = point.x;
   ball.y = point.y;
   ball.x += sin(toRadians((c/8) * 360));
   ball.y += cos(toRadians((c/8) * 360));
   circles.add(ball);
}
```

If you don't know what "sin" and "cos" do, or what "toRadians" means, just Google something like: "Sine Cosine Trigonometry". You'll find plenty of tutorials.

Here, I found this. It will teach you what "sin", "cos" and "radians" mean.
http://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry

Obviously you could just stick with grapefrukt's answer, it works, but if you want to know what's really going on behind the hood in "Point.polar", check out those videos.